# R: Disappearing Graphs

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, data-visualization, interactive

I am using the R programming language. Using the following code, I made these interactive time series graphs:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

library(dplyr)
#generate data
set.seed(123)

######

var = rnorm(731, 85,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 90:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}


result_2 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_2$group = "group_b"
result_2$group = as.factor(result_2$group)

a = result_2 %>%
  plot_ly(x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  add_lines(frame=~var,hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~ paste0("Month: ",month, "<br>",
                            "Mean: ", mean, "<br>",
                            "Total: ", mean(mean))) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "title"),
         xaxis = list(tickangle = -90, tickformat = "%m-%Y"))



######


var = rnorm(731, 75,2)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)

vals <- 75:80
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
    
    data$var_i = i
    data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
    
    #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
    aggregate_i = data %>%
        mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
        group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
        summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
    
    #combine files together
    
    aggregate_i$var = i
    aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
    
    count <- count + 1
    combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
    
}


result_3 <- bind_rows(combine)
result_3$group = "group_b"
result_3$group = as.factor(result_3$group)

b = result_3 %>%
  plot_ly(x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  add_lines(frame=~var,hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~ paste0("Month: ",month, "<br>",
                            "Mean: ", mean, "<br>",
                            "Total: ", mean(mean))) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "title"),
         xaxis = list(tickangle = -90, tickformat = "%m-%Y"))

##### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180563/r-updating-hover-text


 a = plot_ly(result_2, x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  add_lines(frame=~var,hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~ paste0("Month: ",month, "<br>",
                            "Mean: ", mean, "<br>",
                            "Total: ", mean(mean))) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "title1"),
         xaxis = list(tickangle = -90, tickformat = "%m-%Y"))


b = plot_ly(result_3, x=~month, y=~mean, color=~group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  add_lines(frame=~var,hoverinfo = "text",
            text = ~ paste0("Month: ",month, "<br>",
                            "Mean: ", mean, "<br>",
                            "Total: ", mean(mean))) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "title2"),
         xaxis = list(tickangle = -90, tickformat = "%m-%Y"))

#view plots

a

b
```

These two graphs work fine when you view them individually:

[image]

But when I try to use the `plotly::subplot()` command, the second graph disappears:

```
subplot(a,b, nrows=1)
```

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and is there a way to fix this? Is there also a way to use the `ggplot2::facet_wrap()` command in this instance to "synchronize" both graphs together (like here: [R: "tie" two graphs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129000/r-tie-two-graphs-together)) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame axes dont intersect at any point so you wont expect to see both charts at the same time Try this and press play and you will see the transition.

```
subplot(b,a) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 300, transition = 100, easing="elastic") %>%
  animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix=NULL, font=list(color="red", size=40)))
```

Each chart will appear when the frame number gets into its frame range.

Comment: thank you for your answer! this again worked perfectly! is it possible to have two separate "sliders" - one for each graph?

Comment: I am afraid this is something I am not aware of. But if there is, you will probably find it here https://community.plotly.com/c/api/r/9 after some digging around

Comment: Thanks... I'll keep digging. Your help has been greatly Appreciated. Did you have any ideas for this one here!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic ... i am thinking of putting a bounty on it tomorrow